# strtok function returns a NULL value in second call

Tags: c

i have such input string `A,B: A ' B * A B ' * +`

i'm trying to divide it using `strtok` here is my code and output

```
    int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *vars;
    char *formula;
    vars = strtok(argv[1],":");
    formula = strtok(NULL,":");
    printf("%s %s\n", vars,formula);

}

A,B <null>
```

why, when i'm calling strtok for second time it returns `null` ?

Comment: -1 for not checking that `argv[1]` is what you thought it was. It would have been trivial to check and led you to the problem right away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably `argv[1]` contains only `A,B:`, because shell encounters whitespaces as separators of command-line arguments. To have the whole sequence in `argv[1]`, you need to use quotes, i.e.:

```
./myprogram "A,B: A ' B * A B ' * +"
```

Try printing out `argv[1]` to make sure you get correct arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Run your program using

`./test "A,B: A ' B * A B ' * +"`  Notice the double quotes

test - name of executable